# How i can get a get-server-time with python?

Tags: python, server, get

I need make simple script on python with get-server-time, which can get time from server, how a can got it?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create a server. One of the simplest options would be using a third-party module for this. For instance, [flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/) is a popular web framework with a built-in server:

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    return current_time
```

Save it to `server.py` and then run using:

```
> export FLASK_APP=server.py
> flask run
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

Access `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` from your browser or using `wget http://127.0.0.1:5000/` or `curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/`.